# Removing Duplicates from 2d array and updating it in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

I have a 2d array holding values like the following:

array - JK(K, NC)

"K" Stores Total No of Items
"NC" Stores Items

I need to remove the duplicates From "NC" 
and also update "K" (i.e the total items) after removing the duplicates.

*4* - 5,    6,  7,  **5**
*6* - 7,    6,  9,  10, 11, **7**
*4* - 8,    7,  15, **8**
*9* - 12,   15, 16, **12**, 17, 18, 19, 20, **16**
*3* - 26,   27, **26**
*3* - 20,   19, **20**
*6* - 21,   33, **33**, 34, 35, **21**
*8* - 19,   33, 34, 18, 38, 39, 40, **34**
*5* - 39,   40, 38, 43, **40**
*6* - 41,   44, **44**, 45, 46, **41**
*3* - 20,   19, **20**
*6* - 21,   33, **33**, 34, 35, **21**
*8* - 19,   33, 34, 18, 38, 39, 40, **34**

Comment: What is the code you have already tried? Is the order of values in the string of importance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA, remove duplicates from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870095/vba-remove-duplicates-from-array)

Comment: @Moosli This question is different, as it doesn't want to remove duplicate array entries, it wants to remove duplicates from strings, which are in an array.

Comment: @Luuklag For me not really evident from the question, it could also be a 2 Dimensional Array be with different lengths of the two second dimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function, something like this

```
Function RemoveDupes(strInput As String) As Variant()

'   Uses Microsoft Scripting Runtime referece

Dim arrSplit() As String
Dim lngCounter As Long
Dim dicDupeCheck As New Scripting.dictionary

arrSplit = Split(strInput, Chr(32))

For lngCounter = 0 To UBound(arrSplit) - 1

    If Not dicDupeCheck.Exists(arrSplit(lngCounter)) Then
        dicDupeCheck.Add arrSplit(lngCounter), arrSplit(lngCounter)
    End If

Next lngCounter

RemoveDupes = Array(dicDupeCheck.Count, Join(dicDupeCheck.Items(), " "))

Erase arrSplit

End Function
```

This will then be used as follows

`RemoveDupes("12 15 16 12 17 18 19 20 16")(0)` will give the count, and `RemoveDupes("12 15 16 12 17 18 19 20 16")(1)` will give the non-dupe output.

Or set an array to removedupes and use that, so `arr=RemoveDupes("12 15 16 12 17 18 19 20 16")` then `OriginalArray(x)=arr(0) & " - " & arr(1)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Solution based on the Entries and Code from [@tigeravatar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2665425/tigeravatar) and [@Jeeped](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4039065/jeeped) with you could have find here on Stack overflow, so a big thanks to this guys.

[Removing Duplicate values from a string in Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127581/removing-duplicate-values-from-a-string-in-visual-basic)

and

[Multidimensional Arrays with For Loops VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35415078/multidimensional-arrays-with-for-loops-vba)

```
Sub Test()
        Dim strArray(8, 1) As String
        Dim newString As String
        strArray(0, 0) = "4"
        strArray(0, 1) = "5 6 7 5"
        strArray(1, 0) = "6"
        strArray(1, 1) = "7 6 9 10 11 7"
        strArray(2, 0) = "4"
        strArray(2, 1) = "8 7 15 8"
        strArray(3, 0) = "9"
        strArray(3, 1) = "12 15 16 12 17 18 19 20 16"
        strArray(4, 0) = "4"
        strArray(4, 1) = "5 6 7 5"
        strArray(5, 0) = "6"
        strArray(5, 1) = "7 6 9 10 11 7"
        strArray(6, 0) = "9"
        strArray(6, 1) = "12 15 16 12 17 18 19 20 16"

        For i = 0 To UBound(strArray, 1)
                newString = DeDupeString(strArray(i, 1), " ")
                strArray(i, 0) = UBound(Split(newString, " ")) + 1
                strArray(i, 1) = newString
        Next i
    End Sub

    Function DeDupeString(ByVal sInput As String, Optional ByVal sDelimiter As String = ",") As String
        Dim varSection As Variant
        Dim sTemp As String
        varSection = Split(sInput, sDelimiter)
        For Each varSection In Split(sInput, sDelimiter)
            If InStr(1, sDelimiter & sTemp & sDelimiter, sDelimiter & varSection & sDelimiter, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                sTemp = sTemp & sDelimiter & varSection
            End If
        Next varSection
        DeDupeString = Mid(sTemp, Len(sDelimiter) + 1)
    End Function
```

Comment: Nice solution. If only people themselves learned to google ;)